# Page has horizontal scroll which I can't get rid of

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

Please see https://simplybikestuff-staging-com.stackstaging.com/
I've gone through front page and removed code snippets to try get to the issue, but still no - I cannot get rid of the horizontal scrollbar.

The theme is using Sydney theme, with Bootstrap.

Comment: It's your footer. Start there. Here's a tip: start deleting elements in the elements panel until it goes away so you can isolate what is doing it. We are not quite the people to go and debug your complete website though, Stack Overflow tends to deal with more specific questions where I don't become a customer of your website.

Comment: thanks for the helpful comment 'somethinghere'... this is exactly what i've been doing.

Comment: Are you really dissing me for trying to help? Djeezus the nerve to annoy people who actually tried looking at your issue. Maybe mention what you have tried properly? Have a look at [how to ask a proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that isn't just a link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure there is something wrong with the footer section (see the attachment below).

[image]

These images are also problematic because of undefined height or width.

[image]

You have to take a closer look and spend time on the footer to get your problem resolved.